# put a index.php (or .html) file on every folder of a site, is a good security practice?

Tags: php, security, webserver

I've heard this many and many times: "create a index.php on every folder in your web server to make sure users will not see a list of files in the folders"

is that true? I'm in need of some good pratices for security.

Comment: You can prevent directory listings with an .htaccess file or Apache configuration.

Comment: Not all sites have PHP enabled or installed. `index.html` is a better choice for such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Yes.

Having a default document may indeed prevent a directory listing to be outputted, but:

- You could prevent directory listings in other ways (.htaccess, server configuration)
- One could still find files if they guess the file name.
- You could put all files outside of the document root and only have a single script that routes all urls. Thus, there is nothing to list.

So while you're right, it is easy to forget a directory, and a lot of work to create all those files. And it only protects your from listing, and only if index.html is indeed the default document name (again: server configuration). It doesn't prevent any direct access to your script, so please please please use a more proper security.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that but you can simply block that with`.htaccess` like this.

Prevent directory listing with .htaccess
`Options -Indexes`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good practice. It keeps users from drilling down and figuring out your whole directory structure - so that if they're looking for vulnerabilities, their work is a little harder.

Answer (score 1):

In **Apache HTTPd .htaccess** use:

```
Options -Indexes
```

and in **Microsoft IIS web.config** use:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" /><!-- THIS -->
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Regards. Each webserver has its own way, but avoid index.html in folders.
Using the webserver features for this is safer and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a better solution be to disable directory listing from your server configuration file? Your idea sounds like a hack to me..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting index file inside every and each folder, you can disable directory listings by adding the following line to the .htaccess file in your public_html folder:

```
Options -Indexes
```